# Alternative to bring OpenStreetMap Basemaps into ArcMap

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, software-recommendations, performance, arcgis-online-basemaps

The standard ArcGIS OpenStreetMap basemap tiles have been performing quite slow as of late. I was curious if there was a (preferably free) alternative service to bring OpenStreetMap basemap tiles into ArcMap.

Most people here vastly prefer the OSM Maps to ESRI's version of Streetmap as a basemap. I was researching on OpenStreetMaps wiki and could not find one that was working in ArcMap sufficiently as of yet.